# JavaScript Proxy target object conflicts with property descriptors

Tags: javascript, es6-proxy

I'm creating a virtualized object that lazily builds its properties with a rules engine as a technique to skip calculating values that are never read. For this, I'm using a `Proxy`. It seems like proxies sort of serve double-duty for both access forwarding and virtualizing; in my case, I mostly care about the latter, not the former.

The problem I'm having has to do with trying to implement the `getOwnPropertyDescriptor` trap in the proxy. When doing so I get the error:

> TypeError: 'getOwnPropertyDescriptor' on proxy: trap returned descriptor for property 'foo' that is incompatible with the existing property in the proxy target

Because I'm not actually forwarding requests to a wrapped object, I've been using an `Object.freeze({})` as the first argument passed to `new Proxy(...)`.

```js
function createLazyRuleEvaluator(rulesEngine, settings) {
  const dummyObj = Object.freeze({});
  Object.preventExtensions(dummyObj);

  const valueCache = new Map();

  const handlers = {
    get(baseValue, prop, target) {
      if (valueCache.has(prop)) 
        return valueCache.get(prop);

      const value = rulesEngine.resolveValue(settings, prop);
      valueCache.set(prop, value);
      return value;
    },

    getOwnPropertyDescriptor(baseValue, prop) {
      return !propIsInSettings(prop, settings) ? undefined : {
        configurable: false,
        enumerable: true,
        get() {
          return handlers.get(baseValue, prop, null);
        }
      };
    },
  };

  return new Proxy(dummyObj, handlers);
}

// This throws
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(createLazyRuleEvaluator(/*...*/), 'foo');
```

The proxy object is meant to resemble a object with read-only properties that can't be extended or have any other such fanciness. I tried using a frozen and non-extensible object, but I'm still told the property descriptor is incompatible.

When I try using a non-frozen object as the proxy target, then I get a different type error:

> TypeError: 'getOwnPropertyDescriptor' on proxy: trap reported non-configurability for property 'foo' which is either non-existent or configurable in the proxy target

What am I doing wrong here? Is there any way I can have my proxy exhibit non-configurability?

Comment: "*I'm not actually forwarding requests to a wrapped object*" - yes you are. All the requests that you didn't write a trap handler for are still forwarded to the object, like `has` or `set`.

Comment: No, I'm not. The code as posted is not complete (I'm using TDD and hit this snag). I'll be implementing all the trap handlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consult the list of [invariants](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/getOwnPropertyDescriptor#Invariants) for `handler.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()`, which unfortunately includes these:

> - A property cannot be reported as existent, if it does not exist as an own property of the target object and the target object is not extensible.
> - A property cannot be reported as non-configurable, if it does not exist as an own property of the target object or if it exists as a configurable own property of the target object.

Since your `target` is a frozen, empty object, the only valid return value for your `handler.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()` trap is `undefined`.

---

To address the underlying question though, lazily initialize your property descriptors when they're attempted to be accessed:

```js
function createLazyRuleEvaluator(rulesEngine, settings) {
  const dummyObj = Object.create(null);
  const valueCache = new Map();
  const handlers = {
    get(target, prop) {
      if (valueCache.has(prop)) 
        return valueCache.get(prop);

      const value = prop + '_value'; // rulesEngine.resolveValue(settings, prop)
      valueCache.set(prop, value);
      return value;
    },
    getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, prop) {
      const descriptor =
        Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, prop) ||
        { value: handlers.get(target, prop) };

      Object.defineProperty(target, prop, descriptor);
      return descriptor;
    },
  };

  return new Proxy(dummyObj, handlers);
}

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(createLazyRuleEvaluator(/*...*/), 'foo'));
```

You can follow this pattern for each of the method traps to preempt unwanted mutations to your `dummyObj` by lazily initializing any properties accessed.

Comment: So does this mean it's impossible to create a fully virtual proxy that presents as non-extensible?

Comment: @Jacob that's not necessarily true. Give me a few minutes to try out an idea and I'll update my answer. It might be possible to lazily define properties on the target object _before_ returning from `getOwnPropertyDescriptor()` so that the invariants are not technically violated.

Comment: @Jacob before I do that though, could you update your question with an example implementation of `handler.get()`? My edit will be much more helpful with that context.

Comment: Sure, done (hopefully is enough to get this across).

Comment: @Jacob does this seem doable? The `Object.create(null)` isn't strictly necessary, it could work just as well with `{}`.

Comment: @Jacob I see your edit. Maybe it's not obvious but the main key to my answer is the call to `Object.defineProperty(target, prop, descriptor);` before `return`ing from `handlers.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()`

Comment: That technique looks like it could work. Going to play with it.

Comment: Excellent! Seems weird to need this workaround, but it definitely works.

Comment: @Jacob it's not weird. The invariants are imposed such that an object could conceivably exist with said observable behavior. The `Proxy` is not allowed to behave inconsistently, in summary.

Comment: I mean it's weird if you expect that a `Proxy` can be used to make a virtual object from scratch; all these constraints relating to the target object make doing this really hacky when you don't actually want this thing to have anything to do with a target. Another example of strangeness now is that I can't seem to implement `isExtensible` such where it returns `false`.

Comment: Virtualization is rarely trivial, but you're making it harder for yourself by requiring the proxy to handle all reflection methods in addition to normal access.

Comment: If I skipped the reflection methods that would make things simpler, but then reflection methods would return invalid results. I want to make sure this object looks as accurate as possible during reflection.